# VS Solution Architecture Web App + WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I have an ASP.NET Web App running on IIS from a Visual Studio solution with n-tier architecture.

I am developping a WCF service.

I want both web app and wcf service to run on the same IIS web site.

Should I add this service in the existing web project or can I create a new projet inside my solution ?

If it's possible, how can I publish two projects on same IIS website ?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a new WCF Service library project in my visual studio solution. Then I've added a reference to it in a single svc file with following line of code :

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Full.Namespace.ServiceName" %>
```

For the second question : I don't need it anymore.